# Webpack - import a file with only global constants

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a file with global constants that i am trying to import in another js file so that I can use the constants in its code.

**globalConstant.js**

```
global.RoutesOffersPage =  {
  routes: [
    { url: '/fr',
      title: "page daccueil france"
    },
    { url:'/fr/dothis',
      title: "trop sympa"
    }

  ]
}
global.RoutesActionPage =  {
  routes: [    
    { url: '/fr/action',
      title: 'page d'action'
    }
  ]
}
export { global.RoutesOffersPage }; 
export { global.RoutesActionPage };
```

And I would like to use those global variables in my webpack.config.js

**webpack.config.js**

```
import { global.RoutesOffersPage } from './globalConstant.js'
import { global.RoutesActionPage } from './globalConstant.js'

var templateOffersPage = ejs.compile(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/offersPageTemplate.ejs', 'utf-8'))
var paths = global.RoutesOffersPage.routes.map(r => r.url);
var paths2 = global.RoutesActionPage.routes.map(r => r.url);
//do stuff
```

But it the build gives me the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I usually know how to import when there's a function but here it's just constant 'global.constants'. I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `import` thanks to webpack, but as webpack does not recursively bundle its own settings, you cannot use it in the webpack config. You have to go back to require there:

```
require('./globalConstant.js');

global.RoutesOfferPage/*...*/
```

Comment: I see, trying it now

Comment: webpack is so powerful, but sometimes you got to use the basics:) thanks it worked!